# A quick question regarding Green's Functions

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I've been given the following conditions for some 3D function, $\phi$;

$$\nabla^2 \phi(x,y,x) = 0$$
$$\phi(x,y,0) = f(x,y)$$

My question is, would the equivalent Green's function problem be;
$$\nabla^2 G = \delta(\vec x - \vec x_0)$$
$$G(x,y,0) = 0$$

Or...
$$\nabla^2 G = 0$$
$$G(x,y,0) = \delta(\vec x - \vec x_0)$$

Any insight would be great!! :)

Comment: If I understood the formulation correctly (Laplace or Poisson equation on a half-space), then it is the first version, $\triangle G = \delta(x-x_0)$ with zero boundary conditions. The classical application of method of images (reflection)/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, [Green's function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green's_function#Definition_and_uses) of a PDE is a function that solves the PDE (in a distributional sense) with the source term replaced by delta function. In this case, $\nabla^2 G=\delta$. (I.e., what uvs said in a comment.)

I would not say it's an *equivalent*  problem: after all, finding Green's function is just one (big) step toward solving the PDE; also, other methods exist that do not involve Green's function.

Comment: Thank you!! I just wanted a bit of clarification. We've been asked to solve a particular PDE problem using the method of images and the Green's function, and I just wanted to make sure my initial approach was correct. I've gone on further and solved the problem successfully, so thanks!!